# Azure Data Factory - Why does my ForEach block not count my stored procedure as an activity?

Tags: azure, stored-procedures, foreach, azure-data-factory

I am trying to create the following:

- Retrieve file names form an Azure blob container
- For each file name write a record into a table on my Azure SQL database

What I expected would work:

ROOT LEVEL PIPELINE

[image: Root level pipeline]

FOREACH LEVEL

[image: ForEach level]

However, when I try to validate or debug this configuration ADF complains that I have no activities, even though I have already configured the stored procedure in the `ForEach` block.

**Solution**: Insert a dummy SetVariable into the ForEach level. Now it recognises my stored procedure and `SetVariable` and my code runs without any issues.

Surely there must be a better way for my ForEach to work without having to insert a dummy SetVariable. Or am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Seems like hitting the refresh button was not was not enough. After closing my browser and trying again it finally recognized my stored procedure.